# Facebook Meta Tag - og:description for database value with strip_tags() and substr()

Tags: facebook

```
$descpp = substr($fetchForumData[0]['descp'], 0, 300)."...";
// echo $descrp    {As it shows correctly as the description data from database limit to 300 words via echo}
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($descpp); ?>" />
```

The following script not working and shows result 
on facebook as '....' rather than '$descpp + .....'

And I already debug via http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug also.

What is missing? Kindly advice as soon as possible.

Comment: What does <?php echo $fetchForumData[0]['descp']; ?> produces?

Comment: And for <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $fetchForumData[0]['descp']; ?>" />... its shows complete content on the top of the article page and after comment via facebook comment plugin it shows blank space on facebook timeline.

Comment: May you provide the link so I can help you debugging?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Anyone know about its solution? Or help?

Comment: Can't you provide the link so I can help you?